# How to make a link in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm trying to make a link in the form of an image, so that the person navigates directly to the page that image is linked to. However I have no idea how to do this. Right now I have the image itself but when I click it it leads to a whole other blank page.

Can this be done using the tools of wordpress or maybe I need to download a plugin? Or perhaps I need to use HTML codes or something of the sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert a link using an image from your computer, follow these steps:

Go to a post or page editing screen. Click the Add Media button.
Add Media Button
Upload a new image, or click the Media Library tab and click the image you’d like to use as a link.
frommedia
You’ll be able to see the image’s Attachment Details. Choose the Custom URL option under Attachment Display Settings. Type in the URL to which you want the image to link to.
attachmentdetails
Click the Insert into post button.
The image is inserted into your post and linked to whatever was typed in the Link To field.
image with link inside post
↑ Table of Contents ↑
Link to an Image URL

To insert a link using an image stored somewhere else on the Internet, follow these steps:

Click the Add Media button.
Add Media Button
Click the From URL link.
from url
Type the URL of the image file into the URL text box. Your image will show up along with some options. Choose Custom URL under the Link To section and type in the URL to which you want the image to link to.
imagefromurl
Click the Insert into post button.
The image is inserted into your post and linked to the web site you set.
image with link inside post

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="http://yourlink" target="_blank"><img src="your image link" /></a>
```

You need to click on TEXT tab in the WP Post dashboard and type some html ... 
also need to know that there is no plugin for anything you imagine...  some things are simple enough and a lot of people can do it on their own

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly all you need to do is wrap a `<a href=""></a>` around the `<img src="">`:

```
<a href="http://example.com"><img src="imagelink"></a>
```

The above will have an image and if you click on the image then it will bring you to http://example.com